# Two concerns about this passage

Tags: sentence, paraphrasing

> Junior youth groups on the island are particularly thriving, **urged on** by the support of village chiefs who see how the participants are spiritually empowered. Encouraged by the unity and dedication that exist among them, **these young people have not only dispelled the languor of passivity in themselves but have, through various practical projects, found means to work for the betterment of their community** , and as a result, those of all ages, **not least their own parents, have been galvanized into constructive action** . Among the believers and the wider society, the bounty of being able to turn to a Local Spiritual Assembly for guidance and for the resolution of difficult situations is being recognized, and in turn, the decisions of the Spiritual Assemblies are increasingly characterized by wisdom and sensitivity. There is much here to indicate that, when the elements of the Plan’s framework for action are combined into a coherent whole, the impact on a population can be profound.

1. Could you simplify this part in simple English, please? **these young people have not only dispelled the languor of passivity in themselves but have, through various practical projects, found means to work for the betterment of their community**
2. Could you also paraphrase this part, please? A million thanks. **and as a result, those of all ages, **not least their own parents, have been galvanized into constructive action**

Comment: Which words do you not understand?

Comment: @Jim - "Not least" and "languor of themselves"

Comment: @user5036 You have at least one answer here. For future queries, please ask only one question per question, and make it clear exactly what it is that you are asking about. ELU is not a comprehension service; you need to distil your question to the relevant part of the "concern".

Answer (score 2):

1. These young people have been energized by taking part in practical projects that benefit the community.
2. As a result people of all ages, including the parents, have been motivated to become socially active.

Comment: Preface to #1: In contrast to their previous laziness.....